# Getting 500 error with laravel and POST method

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-500

I get this output when client send a POST http request.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8004/api/ciudadano/sinup' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
>
> POST http://127.0.0.1:8004/api/ciudadano/sinup net::ERR_FAILED 500

It looks like it a CORS policy problem.

I alredy create this middleware - Cors.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        $response->header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
        $response->header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials","true");
        $response->header("Access-Control-Max-Age","600");    // cache for 10 minutes

        $response->header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"); //Make sure you remove those you do not want to support

        $response->header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Application");

        return $response;
    }
}
```

And I added this line \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class in Kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array<int, class-string|string>
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
        \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array<string, array<int, class-string|string>>
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:api',

            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array<string, class-string|string>
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'auth.session' => \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \App\Http\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    ];
}
```

I also try fruitcake/laravel-cors package; installing it whit: composer require fruitcake/laravel-cors

and added this line in kernel.php
\Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,

```
protected $middleware = [
  \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
   // ...
   // ...
];
```

What's happening?

this is the routes, api.php:

```
Route::get ('/test', function (){
    return ("Backend OK");
});

Route::post('/ciudadano/sinup', 'App\Http\Controllers\CiudadanoController@store');
```

the url with the get method http://127.0.0.1:8004/api/test is working fine!

and this is the controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CiudadanoController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request);
        $this->validate($request, [
            'cuil'=>'required',
            'nombre'=>'required',
            'apellido'=>'required',
            'email'=>'required',
            'password'=>'required',
        ]);

        //debería corroborar el cuil con el nombre y el apellido con authenticar

        $ciudadano = Ciudadano::create($request->all());
        //acá debería devolver un token
        dd($ciudadano);

        $ciudadano->save();
        return ("OK");
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: What are you using for consuming your Laravel?

Comment: Laravel version 9

Answer (score 1):

Laravel already has a `cors.php` config file built in. You need to configure your CORS logic in that file.

If you want to just allow everything, use an asterisk:

```php
'paths' => ['*'],
```

Comment: I already changed the path line with '*' but the problems continue in cors.php

Answer (score 1):

update the config to define the paths you want to run the CORS service on :

change paths array to **'paths' => ['*']**

Comment: I already changed the path line with '*'  in cors.php but the problems continue